# Multiple terms not working on taxonomy

Tags: query, terms, tax-query

I need multiple terms support my WordPress theme -

```
$boards = get_user_meta($user_ID, '_Following Board ID');
$pboards = get_user_meta($user_ID, '_Board Parent ID');
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'board',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( '$pboards[0]', '$boards[0]' )
        )
    ),
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

I need following and parent boards post list

Comment: You syntax is wrong, do not add variables in single quotes. Remove them. `array( '$pboards[0]', '$boards[0]' )` should be `array( $pboards[0], $boards[0] )`. Also, make sure that you actually get have the values that you expect them to be. Also, you field value should be `term_id`, not `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `field` value to `term_id`, since there is no `id` value for that option.

Ref: [`WP_Query` Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: Although `id` is not valid and wrong syntax, it works, so will any junk that you add in there as `field` value. If `name` or `slug` is not used as `field` value, it defaults to `term_id` regardless of value passed. :-)

Comment: Nothing work bro

Comment: Are $pboards[0] and $boards[0] integers? And I assume there is get_posts or new WP_Query for that $args variable too.

Comment: http://www.kisukhon.com view now only show Following boards post

Comment: Add more relevant code to the question, its hard to see why the query fails.